# memcpy behaves differently with optimization flags compared to without

Tags: c, gcc, memcpy, buffer-overflow

Consider this demo programme:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} mystruct;

int main() {
    int TOO_BIG = getpagesize();
    int SIZE = sizeof(mystruct);
    mystruct foo = {
        123, 323, 232
    };

    mystruct bar;
    memset(&bar, 0, SIZE);
    memcpy(&bar, &foo, TOO_BIG);
}
```

I compile this two ways:

1. `gcc -O2 -o buffer -Wall buffer.c`
2. `gcc -g -o buffer_debug -Wall buffer.c`

i.e. the first time with optimizations enabled, the second time with debug flags and no optimization.

The first thing to notice is that there are no warnings when compiling, despite `getpagesize` returning a value that will cause buffer overflow with `memcpy`.

Secondly, running the first programme produces:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

whereas the second produces

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

or, and you'll have to believe me here since I can't reproduce this with the demo programme, sometimes **no warning at all**. The programme doesn't even interrupt, it runs as normal. This was a behaviour I encountered with some more complex code, which made it difficult to debug until I realised that there was a buffer overflow happening.

My question is: why are there two different behaviours with different build flags? And why does this sometimes execute with no errors when built as a debug build, but always errors when built with optimizations?

Comment: Compilers aren't required to produce diagnostics for undefined behaviour. Similarly, programs with UB may run "normally" or produce runtime errors or something else.

Comment: Buffer overflow results in undefined behaviour and undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: A program with undefined behaviour is not required to do the same thing every time: that would be defined behaviour. And the different codes are not required to have the same undefined effects.

Comment: @jumbot your question is not stupid, just that there are many variations of "Why is there different undefined behavior in X case than Y case." For example I remember one question where someone was asking why they were getting a bus error after trying to write to a string literal rather than a segfualt. The question may sound different, but the answer is the same for every one of these: undefined behavior is undefined. You could quite literally have dragons invade your house at running this program and it would not violate the C standard because it is undefined behavior where anything's allowed

Comment: It is a well presented question. I am not, though, of the "your cat will turn green" school, which is plain silly.

Comment: @WeatherVane _I am not, though, of the "your cat will turn green" school, which is plain silly_ [you never know ;)](https://www.boredpanda.com/green-cat-varna-bulgaria/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 nice one but that was not the result of a rogue compiler. The explanation is much simpler: the cat was sleeping where paint is stored. A compiler, when dealing with an undefined situation does not "do what it likes", or "nothing", it does something reasonable, otherwise it does what it is expected to do. Compilers have to make it to market. It would be a fine thing if every time you have a bug, the computer catches fire.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah of course, in reality, your generated program will neither spawn dragons outside your house and nor will it make your cat green. I exaggerated just a tad bit there, but only to make my point clear. I've looked over the question a few more times and you're right, it is well-formed, better than the example I mentioned at least, so it's earned my upvote still.

Comment: @WeatherVane Some compilers, most notably open the source ones, aren't too concerned with quality of implementation, but obsessed with producing the most efficient code in any given situation. This can be done by exploiting UB. For example by leaving the paint shop unlocked to save time, since by law nobody should be breaking in there. Now if some cat thread which shouldn't have process access gets it anyway, then goes to subclass your WM_PAINT and takes a `Sleep()` in it, then that's no fault of the compiler, right? It's that darn cat abusing exploits.

Comment: @Lundin yeah, but *my* cat is already green so it is a benign bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *..I can't reproduce this with the demo program, sometimes no warning at all...*

The [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3) directives are very broad, there is no requirement for the compiler to issue any warnings for a program that exhibits this behavior:

> *why are there two different behaviours with different build flags? And why does this sometimes execute with no errors when built as a debug build, but always errors when built with optimizations?*

Compiler optimizations tend to optimize away unused variables, if [I compile your code](https://godbolt.org/z/dsa4KcP5b) with optimizations enabled I don't get a segmentation fault, looking at the assembly (link above), you'll notice that the problematic variables are optimized away, and `memcpy` doesn't get called, so there is no reason for it to not compile successfuly, the program exits with success code 0, whereas if don't optimize it, the undefined behavior manifests itself, and the program exits with code 139, classic segmentation fault exit code.

As you can see these results are different from yours and that is one of the *features* of undefined behavior, different compilers, systems or even compiler versions can behave in a completely different way.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing memory behind what's been allocated is undefined behavior, which means the compiler is allowed to do anything. When there are no optimizations, the compiler may try to guess and do something reasonable. When optimizations are turned on, the compiler may take advantage of the fact that any behavior is allowed to do something that runs faster.

Comment: Your last two words should be changed to *crashes faster*

Comment: @tofro which would not be true at all. It might as well make the program stable because the undefined behavior is removed from the binary.

Answer (score 1):

> The first thing to notice is that there are no warnings when compiling, despite getpagesize returning a value that will cause buffer overflow with memcpy.

That is the programmer's responsibility to fix, not the compiler. You'll be very lucky if a compiler manages to find potential buffer overflows for you. Its job is to check that your code is valid C then translate it to machine code.

If you want a tool that catches bugs, they are called static analysers and that's a different type of program. At some extent, static analysis might be integrated in a compiler as a feature. There is one for clang, but most static analysers are commercial tools and not open source.

> Secondly, running the first programme produces: ... whereas the second produces

Undefined behavior simply means there is no defined behavior. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486). Meaning there's not likely anything to learn from examining the results, no interesting mystery to solve. In one case it apparently accessed forbidden memory, in the other case it mangled a poor little "stack canary". The difference will be related to different memory layouts. Who cares - bugs are bugs. Focus on *why* the bug happened (you already know!), instead of trying to make sense of the undefined results.

Now when I run your code with optimizations *actually* enabled for real (`gcc -O2` on an x86 Linux), the compiler gives me

```
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    getpagesize
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

With optimizations actually enabled, it didn't even bother calling memcpy & friends because there are no side effects and the variables aren't used, so they can be safely removed from the executable.

Comment: "instead of trying to make sense of the undefined results" - I was just curious... is that not allowed? :)

Comment: @jumbot Like millions of newbies before you, each coming up with the same "revolutionary mysteries" that must be investigated. The only things you can learn from this though, is bits and pieces of how the compiler generates machine code for the given system/ABI. If you truly wish to learn something of value, then instead of those random bits & pieces you ended up with through your UB, you would actually study the ABI, calling convention, stack frame format etc etc of the given system. These are not a trivial things to study. Yet that is what's required in order to understand the errors.

Comment: *There's not likely anything to learn from examining the results*. I thoroughly disagree. Suppose there is a fault in the functioning of your product, and you find a bug in an unrelated part of the code. The fault goes away. How do you ensure you haven't just moved the side-effect of an *another* bug which is undiscovered? You do that by examining what actually was happening, to assure yourself that the bug you found *was* responsible for the fault observed elsewhere. This is especially important in code that will be distributed, perhaps as firmware, across the world.

Comment: I don't remember ever describing this as revolutionary... I wanted to know something, I couldn't find an answer for my specific situation, so I asked here. And what happens? I get told that I shouldn't be asking the question and to go away and 'actually study the ABI' etc., then downvoted simply because some people think that the question is too far beneath them. We didn't all study computer science at university, and some of us have never had any formal education in it, Lundin.

Comment: @WeatherVane The true lesson to learn is: how to write code so that bugs don't cause unrelated parts of your code to explode. That is, don't use tight coupling designs. _This_ is what newbies should focus on - learn about best practices. Now do you see any beginner classes teaching proper program design? Not a single one. Instead they have a heavy focus on things with very limited use like learning console I/O APIs, recursive functions, solve i=i++, write addition without + operator... the list goes on.

Comment: @Lundin as you know, exceeding the bounds of a local array can affect anything on the stack: local variables in calling functions and return addresses. That is how the cause and symptom can seem to be unrelated.

Comment: @jumbot I don't remember ever telling you to don't ask the question or go away. In that case I wouldn't have written an answer, see. Also, I didn't down vote. You have to realize though, that some questions have been asked _many_ times before and therefore people eventually get fed up when it gets asked the 100,000th time. Contrary to popular belief, SO is actually not an interactive beginner tutorial. Though as it happens, you can find countless duplicates of old beginner questions if you dig through the SO archives.

Comment: @WeatherVane Which is why one of them best practice rules is: simply _don't_ allocate large arrays/buffers on the stack. Rather than to teach newbies some stack frame format, teach them to always allocate such buffers in other parts of the memory.

Comment: @Lundin the size of the array is completely irrelevant (in this matter). It is the mistaken large index (perhaps from using an uninitialised variable) that is the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane Solution: teach beginners to always initialize their variables. Cure the cause of the problem.

Comment: That's not the only cause, as you well know. It was an example. And yes, you can check the array index, and when developing, I often do.

Comment: @WeatherVane My point is, you can teach people how avoid creating such bugs. Or better yet, teach them to troubleshoot the bug. Such as: okay you get "stack smashed", lets launch a debugger and see if we can find the _cause_. To narrow down at what line the problem is. That's very useful knowledge!